# `targets`: Use a `file` target in the pipeline that has been deleted since the last `tar_make()`

Tags: r, targets-r-package

## Goal

My goal is to use a `file` target that has been deleted since the last `tar_make()` in the target pipeline for further processing.

## Example

An example of this would be a pipeline that attempts to keep an `input` directory of csv's synchronised with another `output` directory.

Any new or modified `files` in an `input` directory would be copied over to the `output` directory. Any files deleted from the `input` directory would be subsequently deleted from the `output` directory on the next `tar_make`.

## What I've Tried

I've tried reading the last recorded metadata of the `paths` object (using `targets::tar_read("paths")`) and intersecting those files that no longer show up in the current `input` directory.

I'm not sure how to distinguish between `deleted` and `added`/`modified` files, or where a call to `fs::file_delete()` would go in the pipeline.

## Reprex

This reprex provides a template of the undesirable functionality. I.e., it leaves the `input` directory with fewer files than `output` after deleting a file from `input`

```r
library(fs)
library(targets)

setwd(fs::path_temp())

# Create an example Targets Script
# Uses code from dynamic branching section of targets manual
targets::tar_script({
    library(targets)

    path <- fs::dir_ls("input/", type = "file")

    list(
        tar_target(paths, path),
        tar_target(files, paths, format = "file", pattern = map(paths)),
        tar_target(output, fs::file_copy(files, "output/"), format = "file", pattern = map(files))
    )
})

# Set Up example directories
fs::dir_create("input")
fs::dir_create("output")

# Create example files
fs::file_touch(fs::file_temp(paste0("file", 1:3), "input", ext = ".csv"))

# Workflow

# Show Current State of directories
fs::dir_ls("input")
#> input/file11e8c5485285b.csv input/file21e8c2d1f56d7.csv 
#> input/file31e8c11f37d7c.csv
fs::dir_ls("output")
#> character(0)

# Make
targets::tar_make()
#> • start target paths
#> • built target paths [0 seconds]
#> • start branch files_8891df33
#> • built branch files_8891df33 [0 seconds]
#> • start branch files_653f6c5c
#> • built branch files_653f6c5c [0 seconds]
#> • start branch files_54f990fe
#> • built branch files_54f990fe [0 seconds]
#> • built pattern files
#> • start branch output_912b0af5
#> • built branch output_912b0af5 [0 seconds]
#> • start branch output_51d97382
#> • built branch output_51d97382 [0 seconds]
#> • start branch output_f8438c83
#> • built branch output_f8438c83 [0 seconds]
#> • built pattern output
#> • end pipeline [0.12 seconds]
#> Warning message:
#> package 'targets' was built under R version 4.2.2 

# Show Updated State of directories
fs::dir_ls("input")
#> input/file11e8c5485285b.csv input/file21e8c2d1f56d7.csv 
#> input/file31e8c11f37d7c.csv
fs::dir_ls("output")
#> output/file11e8c5485285b.csv output/file21e8c2d1f56d7.csv 
#> output/file31e8c11f37d7c.csv

# Delete an input file
fs::file_delete(fs::dir_ls("input")[1])

# Show Updated State of directories
fs::dir_ls("input")
#> input/file21e8c2d1f56d7.csv input/file31e8c11f37d7c.csv
fs::dir_ls("output")
#> output/file11e8c5485285b.csv output/file21e8c2d1f56d7.csv 
#> output/file31e8c11f37d7c.csv

# Make
targets::tar_make()
#> • start target paths
#> • built target paths [0 seconds]
#> ✔ skip branch files_653f6c5c
#> ✔ skip branch files_54f990fe
#> ✔ skip pattern files
#> ✔ skip branch output_51d97382
#> ✔ skip branch output_f8438c83
#> ✔ skip pattern output
#> • end pipeline [0.09 seconds]
#> Warning message:
#> package 'targets' was built under R version 4.2.2 

# Show final state of directories
fs::dir_ls("input")
#> input/file21e8c2d1f56d7.csv input/file31e8c11f37d7c.csv
fs::dir_ls("output")
#> output/file11e8c5485285b.csv output/file21e8c2d1f56d7.csv 
#> output/file31e8c11f37d7c.csv
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another target downstream which cleans up files that are not supposed to be there. Sketch:

```r
library(targets)

path <- fs::dir_ls("input/", type = "file")

clean_output <- function(output) {
  all_files <- fs::dir_ls("output/", type = "file")
  delete_these <- setdiff(all_files, output)
  unlink(delete_these)
  "output"
}

list(
  tar_target(paths, path),
  tar_target(files, paths, format = "file", pattern = map(paths)),
  tar_target(output, fs::file_copy(files, "output/"), format = "file", pattern = map(files)),
  tar_target(result, clean_output(output), format = "file")
)
```